# Problem with extra space at the bottom of android Webview

Tags: android

I have an Webview in my application where i display the html content using loadData() method. The Problem is HTML content is displayed along with some extra space at the bottom, I could not understand why the white space is coming. This problem is occurring only in Motorola Milestone device(Android 2.1). Please somebody help to sort out this problem.

[image]

Thanks in Advance,
Rajapandian

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At last I found the answer for my own question, I need to append the meta tag along with my HTML content before adding it to the Webview. Please find the Code below

```
 String s="<head><meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi'/></head>";            
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,s+htmlContent,"text/html" , "utf-8",null);
```

The Viewport property inside the meta tag done the trick, please refer the following link for further details.

[Using Viewport in Android Webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)

Regards,
Rajapandian

Comment: Still  some times issue replicate in android 12 and 13.

Answer (score 3):

This blog post solved my problem. I think it'll help. http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/resizing-webview-to-match-the-content-size/

```
   private void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This actually solved the white space issue on 4.4+, but it will also position the webview to top so you have to position it where it should go on that screen

Answer (score 1):

Better use  width property also .Because some devices consider that .

eg:

```
String s="<head><meta name=viewport content=target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, width=device-width/></head>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For who set the viewport according to the accepted answer but still having problem, try removing **padding** and **margin** from HTML and BODY in pages inside the WebView. If you want to keep body padding, add `box-sizing:border-box` to body tag:

```
html{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```