# White space at the bottom of WebView in Android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, whitespace

I'm developing an Android application and I'm loading one google maps iframe in a WebView, just like this one:

http://maps.google.es/maps/empw?url=http:%2F%2Fmaps.google.es%2Fmaps%3Ff%3Dq%26source%3Ds_q%26hl%3Des%26geocode%3D%26q%3Dmadrid%26aq%3D%26sll%3D40.396764,-3.713379%26sspn%3D11.856886,23.269043%26vpsrc%3D0%26ie%3DUTF8%26hq%3D%26hnear%3DMadrid,%2BComunidad%2Bde%2BMadrid%26t%3Dm%26z%3D10%26ll%3D40.416691,-3.700345%26output%3Dembed&hl=es&gl=es

It is showing correctly in Android emulator, but when I try in a real device a white space quite big appears at the bottom of the screen, so you can't see the whole iframe. I tried with two mobiles, one with android 2.2 and another one with android 2.3

I had a look to this one which sounds the same thing:

[Problem with extra space at the bottom of android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172686/problem-with-extra-space-at-the-bottom-of-android-webview)

but it didn't work for me. Also tried some other things I read about like:

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but nothing worked. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A have a same issue, but white space appears at the right side of the screen. But, there is no problems with Android 3.0 and higher. I'm not using `iframe` but problems sounds the same.

Comment: It may be the scrollbar at the bottom of the screen, since you are using WebView. The scrollbar makes a tiny stripe of the same color as your theme. I do not know how to fix it though.

Comment: See if anything here helps!!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086738/android-webview-empty-white-space-at-the-bottom-after-scaling-to-the-device-wi/11087411#11087411

Comment: can you post your xml you have used for the UI ?

Comment: @rahul there is just one WebView. Nothing more. No padding, no margin.

Comment: can you paste your code? xml and java file.

Comment: webview.setOverScrollMode(Webview.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the <body> element at the link you posted has bottom margin of 14px - maybe that's it? You can eliminate it using a JavaScript snippet in your WebView after you have loaded the page, like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginBottom = '0px'");
```

also, there is a 44px margin on the right, if you wanna get rid of that one also, should be something like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginBottom = '0px';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginRight = '0px';");
```

Also, to future-proof your app, you may want to set all four margins to 0, just in case.

Comment: Looks like it's solves the problem of @javi, but what about white space in the left of WebView (read comments).

Comment: Updated the answer, that page also has a right margin, the technique is the same :)

Comment: javi, if the answer helped you, please, consider accepting it.

Comment: This line just prints "0px" in my webview and removes everything else.

Comment: @nilsi That's odd, does it allow you to execute any JavaScript at all?

Comment: Yes it is. I got it working by changing some parts, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the bottom and right margins to 0:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.marginBottom=document.body.style.marginBottom= '0px'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with your `XML`.

Can you check that your `WebView` is not inside the `ScrollView` or anything which is having its inbuilt scroll. It might result in extra white spaces.

Comment: My XML looks like that: <FrameLayout> <WebView /> </FrameLayout>, and nothing more.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. I have put WebView inside ScrollView as I need to render other elements also in the same page. Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me but this did:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function () {document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginBottom = '0'})()");
```