# Android Webview - Empty white space at the bottom after scaling to the device width

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, scrollbar, scale

I am scaling my webview to fit the content to the width of the screen using the following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

This works but now I am getting an empty space at the bottom of the content.  The size (in height) of the empty space is directly proportional to the magnitude of the zoom it is doing.  So for smaller devices, the size is greater.

My feeling is that scroll bars size are not being recalculated after the zoom has taken effect.  This assumption is due to the fact that when zooming-in and out by tapping on the screen, empty space goes away.  Although this is working on Android 2.3 but not on 4.0.

My question how to force the scrollbars to recalculate after the zoom.  Or is there any other solution.

Thanks.

P.S.  Here is how I defined the webview in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:background="#AAFFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Or it could be that the content being viewed is much wider than it is tall, so when you base your zoom on the width, it is making the content view pixel wise shorter than the screen!!!

Comment: no, its definitely taller, and as I said, on 2.3 OS, zooming in and out fixes the scroll bar height, and the white space goes away

Comment: How did you define your webview, within an XML, in code?  Do you have the fill_parent defined for both dimensions of the WebView?  Im kinda shooting in the dark a bit here, but I have to ask :-)

Comment: i've updated my question to add the xml

Comment: Why do you have a webview within a linearlayout within a scrollview, first of all? A WebView inherits from scrollView and implements it's own scrolling, so what is the other scrollview for?  Essentially you will have a scroller within a scroller!!! Secondly I do see that you have "wrap_content" for your WebView' android:layout_height property.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering that myself after I pasted it :)  After removing the ScrollView its looking fine.  Please add your comment as the Answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you have a webview within a linearlayout within a scrollview, first of all? A WebView inherits from scrollView and implements it's own scrolling, so what is the other scrollview for? Essentially you will have a scroller within a scroller!!! Secondly I do see that you have `"wrap_content"` for your WebView' `android:layout_height` property.

Comment: I have a WebView inside a ScrollView because there are other views after the WebView.

Comment: Mine is also same but it solved when I made `layout_height` as `wrap_content` so no need to use webview scroller, there is only parent scrollview for all components.