# Extra white space issue at the bottom of Webview in Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using `Webview` to display `HTML` Data. Sometimes, It works fine but most of time, It is showing `Extra White Space` at the bottom of `Webview`.
It might be Duplicate post, Source : [Problem with extra space at the bottom of android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172686/problem-with-extra-space-at-the-bottom-of-android-webview)
I have tried same thing as per post but it is not working in my case.

```
String s="<head><meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi'/></head>";            
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,s + htmlContent,"text/html" , "utf-8",null);
```

How to prevent this issue ???

**Check below image :** 
[image]

Comment: HTML source code would be helpful.

Comment: @DamienGolding, thank you for reply. But i have replace `Webview` with `TextView` using `ImageGetter`.