# Calculating height when there is embedded tweet Android

Tags: android, twitter

I got issues when load embed twitter into webview, it have  extra space at bottom of view.
I work normal without embed twitter data in html for display in webview
With data:

```
you can get twitter's embed at https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Eembeddedtimeline%7Ctwterm%5Eprofile%3ATwitterDev&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.twitter.com%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Ftwitter-for-websites%2Ftimelines%2Foverview.html
```

[The result when load with webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvfOy.png)

The iOS have the same issues and already resolved at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057113/ios-wkwebview-improperly-calculating-height-when-there-is-embedded-tweet)
I try to embed some data like youtube, it work normal without extra space in bottom.

Comment: Show us your layout xml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with extra space at the bottom of android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172686/problem-with-extra-space-at-the-bottom-of-android-webview)

Comment: no @GokulNathKP, it works normal without twitter's embed

Comment: I fixed this bug because I add Webview into Framelayout. So I just remove framelayout contain webview and it works.